# How to convert a letter in a string to a number in R

Tags: r, string, numbers, type-conversion

I have a data set with a column of values V01, V02, V03,...,V91 among other values such as E000, E001, 402 , and so on. How can I replace the V values with a number like 1000 in this column without converting the column to a vector?

(I can't use the function as.numeric since I don't want my "E..." values become NA and get mixed with the "V..." values.)

Example:
my data looks like:
{V01
527
E54
64.5}

I want it to look like:
{100001
527
E54
64.5}

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub`:

```
x <- c("V01","527","E54", "64.5")
gsub("V","1000",x)

[1] "100001" "527"    "E54"    "64.5"
```

**EDIT** To apply on one column:

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c("V01","527","E54", "64.5"),col2=2)
df$col1 <- gsub("V","1000",df$col1 )
df
    col1 col2
1 100001    2
2    527    2
3    E54    2
4   64.5    2
```

Comment: Thanks for saying. I'm new to this website!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
      mutate(col1 = str_replace(col1, 'V', 1000))
#    col1 col2
#1 100001    2
#2    527    2
#3    E54    2
#4   64.5    2
```

---

Or using `sub` from `base R`

```
df$col1 <- sub("V", 1000, df$col1)
df$col1
#[1] "100001" "527"    "E54"    "64.5"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c("V01","527","E54", "64.5"),col2=2)
```